# Firefox Clearing Cache - Ctrl + F5 doesn't work randomly

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, browser-cache

Running Firefox 31, Windows 7:

I was running into a bug on a website that I'm testing, where some things that did exist but do not anymore, were still showing up. I tried clearing the cache by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but that was not fixing the issue. I then tried clearing cookies, and that still wasn't fixing the issue.

I then tried viewing the site on a different computer -- also running Firefox 31 -- and the site was showing up like it should, with the old stuff that was deleted gone like it should have been. I tried clearing the cache using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on the computer that was having the issues for the 50th time, but to no avail, I was still seeing the bug.

I then tried going into the settings instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, and clearing cache that way, by deleting only the cache. This actually worked for me, and I was no longer seeing the bug.

So with that known, why was I still seeing the cache, even though I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> many times to reload the page without the cache? The code didn't change while I was doing all of this, it just seems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> wasn't working at all for me for some reason (and if I press <kbd>F3</kbd> it does the find function so I know my F-keys are working).

Even the [Firefox support site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) shows that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> can be used to override the cache, but that wasn't working for me. So does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> just randomly not work? What could the issue have been? It feels like I now need to go into the settings every single time I want to reload the page without cache, which is fairly often. I know there are workarounds like disabling cache completely or plugins to remove it on click, but I still want cache to show up sometimes, and if the key combination that firefox itself gives us doesn't work sometimes, who's to say a plugin made by some third party developer won't work randomly either?

Comment: same problem for me. Out of the blue my FFv45.0 suddenly has this problem. F5 or Ctrl+F5 are plain silent and do anything at all. FF45 on another pc doesn't have that issue though.

Comment: Been having the same issue for a while, not sure which Fx version started this. All the shortcuts to reload + purge cache mentioned there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Firefox_and_other_related_browsers don't work for me at the moment :/
The quickest workaround is Ctrl + Shift + Del and then purge cache from here, but that's not very satisfying...

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that Ctrl+F5 _bypasses_ the cache, and does not clear it.  What was the bug related to?  I ask because .htaccess redirects are cached separately from the main cache which Ctrl+F5 bypasses.  Also, did you try a private browsing window?

Comment: @FCTW sorry, this was posted nearly 3 years ago and I don't remember the exact problem I was personally having or other steps I took trying to fix it, aside from what is in the question

Comment: @AlexPodworny  Yeah, I only noticed the age after I had already commented.

Answer (score 2):

## How to get around the issue

If `Ctrl-F5` isn't working, `Ctrl-Shift-R` works as a fine substitute to reload the page without the cache.

## Why this happens

The `Ctrl-F5` key event may be captured by your OS, and so Firefox never sees it. For example, [XFCE captures `Ctrl-F5` key events](https://askubuntu.com/a/179707/497651), and tries to switch to the fifth workspace.

Answer (score 0):

## <**Firefox**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>